# Как правильно обратиться в базу данных?

Tags: javascript, sql, google-spreadsheet

Требуется при нажатии на кнопку в гугл таблицах обратиться в базу данных и дёрнуть sql-функцию. Она вернёт результат. Как лучше, быстрее и эффективнее это реализовать?

Comment: Полагаю обратится как обычно, с защитой от иньекции.

Answer (score 0):

Обработать нажатие на кнопку сможет Гугл-скрипт.

Прямо из скрипта обращаться к порту БД не совсем удобно. Сделайте API-интерфейс к БД. Вариантов много, например по протоколу HTTP/HTTPS. Вопросы безопасности - на совести разработчика, поэтому надо предусмотреть какой-то тип авторизации при таком запросе.

После этого можно слать запросы из Гугл-скрипта при каждом нажатии кнопки и даже получать подтверждение.

В качестве исходной точки рекомендую прочесть [документ от Гугла](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/external).

Comment: Я вас не до конца понял, возможно, если вы уточните, я смогу понять. На данный момент у меня получилось реализовать через express.js

Comment: Тогда уточните, что именно мне следует уточнить... С express.js я не знаком (в той мере, чтобы предложить готовый путь решения). Ваш вопрос был задан в общей форме и я попытался ответить также. Если мы перейдём на конкретику, уточнять придётся много и долго, потому что тема широкая. Но все же, если смогу, кратко уточню.

Comment: Задача состояла в том, чтобы из гугл-скриптов при нажатии на кнопку обратится к базе данных и выгрузить оттуда актуальную информацию. Я не понимал как можно это реализовать, а конкретно, как реализовать максимально быстро back-end часть. Максимально сжатые сроки. Я наткнулся на express.js, который позволяет ловить запросы, и через него обращаемся к бд.

Comment: Отлично. Теперь направляйте соответствующие HTTP запросы из гугл скриптов, используя класс UrlFetchApp (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app). Это позволит Вам передать данные и принять ответ в удобном формате. По указанной ссылке есть немало примеров. А про безопасность я уже писал (ведь запрос к Вашей БД может послать и хакер...)